# High school thesis project about Jupiter's moon Europa

Tags: education, planets, solar-system, moon, jupiter

So basically, I have to write a thesis paper because I'm in the last year of high school. It is an independent research project and the culminating work of my studies in school, so it represents my ability to conduct research and write effectively.

The requirement is that the paper needs to be connected to one of my elective classes. I chose cosmology, so any topic related to cosmology or physics. I've done some research lately and what I would like to write about is Jupiter's moon Europa. More specifically, the question I would like to investigate is "Can humans live on Europa in the future?".

To answer this question, I am going to compare the environment on Europa with that of the Earth. If there are a lot of similiarites, then I will conclude that it is possible to settle on Europa. However, I am worried that it will be virtually impossible to compare the environments simply because there are too many factors to consider. For example, weather conditions, water availability, radiation, pressure, temperature and so on.

So I would like some advice. Firstly, which environmental factors should I include in my paper?

And secondly, if my question "Can humans live on Europa in the future?" is a bit too difficult to answer, then are there any other Europa-related questions that I could investigate instead?

Comment: Whatever response is forthcoming here, have you tried looking at related questions on our [worldbuilding.se] stack. They won't directly tell you how to approach your thesis, but they'll give you some interesting reading around the subject. Eg.: [logistics-of-manned-europa-exploration](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/51289/logistics-of-manned-europa-exploration) and [would-europa-be-a-logical-choice-for-commercial-and-industrial-ice-mining](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/57434/would-europa-be-a-logical-choice-for-commercial-and-industrial-ice-mining).

Comment: Try [space.se].

Comment: A friendly reminder to our community that comments should not be used to post answers to a question. To answer a closed question, first vote to reopen.